# IE removes input placeholder when on focus

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, placeholder

Is there an IE hack so the placeholder remains visible when the input field has focus? Currently placeholder disappears in IE when input has focus. For all other browsers it works fine.
Best thanks

Comment: You could go through a lot of trouble to make a custom overlay which disappears when the user starts typing. Or you can just accept that IE behaves like it does.

Comment: You can try webshims. Here is a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/w3TVB/